# Import/Export XLS-MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, import, export

I deal with export and import with XLS and MySQL. About import. U used [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/) library, but I need edit it and I don't know how to do it. Result of this script are strings separated by commas, but lines are too separated by comma, but I need, that individual lines will be separated by semicolons.

About export I really don't know which script I can use. Ideally, if it was a script that would allow filtration and if resoult would be file, which I can open with Excel (CSV, XLS, ..). I know, that this function have PHPMyAdmin, but I can't use it.

Thank you very much, and sorry for my English :)

Comment: What do you need to edit? The library? or the files that you import?

Comment: If you mean you need a library that can read and write, and allowing you to change the contents of different spreadsheet file formats, then I'd recommend [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) (though I will declare a vested interest as I'm the developer of the library)

Answer (score 0):

[PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) is a PHP-library for import/export from/into various data-sheet formats:

Very versatile and rather transparent API.